# Can such a fuction exist?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Can such real-valued function exist that $\lim_{x\to\infty}(xf(x))=3$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}(xf'(x))=5$, if $f:(1,\infty)→\mathbb{R}$ ?

The origninal problem is that if $f$ satisfies the above conditions, What is $L= \lim_{x\to\infty}(xf''(x))$?
I think $f$ does not exist so this problem is wrong.
$\lim_{x\to\infty}(xf(x))=3$
$\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x))=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}(xf'(x))=5$
$\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty}(f'(x))=0$. If the answer of the problem exist, even $f(x)$ holds up  $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f''(x))=0$ in spite of above situation.

Comment: What is given is only f is second-order differentiable.

Comment: If $\lim_{x\to\infty}(xf'(x))=5$ then $f'(x) > 1/x$ for all sufficiently large $x$. Can you continue?

Comment: Umm.. sorry but what does that means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Martin's hint.

$f'(x)>\frac{1}{x}$ for $x$ sufficiently large means that there exists $M>0$ such that $f'(x)>\frac{1}{x}\,,\forall x\in[M,\infty)$ .

This means that on $[M,x]$ you have

$$\int_{M}^{x}f'(t)\,dt>\int_{M}^{x}\frac{1}{t}\,dt$$

So $f(x)-f(M)\geq\ln(\frac{x}{M})$

This means that $xf(x)\geq x\ln(\frac{x}{M})+xf(M)$.

Now can you conclude that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}xf(x)=\infty$ ?

Comment: @MartinR thanks I have edited. The op clearly mentions that $f$ is differentiable upto 2nd order so it is immediately clear that $f'$ is differentiable and hence continuous and hence it is Riemann integrable in the compact set $[M,x]$ .

Comment: Yes you are right (so I will delete my comment). But for the question in the first paragraph it suffices to assume that $f$ is differentiable. (As someone remarked somewhere: IVT is often stronger than FTC).

Comment: @MartinR How does the IVT help us?

Comment: @FShrike: Sorry, I meant MVT (mean-value theorem): $f(x) - \ln(x)$ has a positive derivative, therefore it is increasing.

Comment: @MartinR Powerful indeed. I’m glad you meant MVT: I was going nuts trying to see an intermediate value theorem path.

Comment: I'm late to reply. I understand Thanks a lot